# Failed to restart Apache server

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, failed

I'm trying to restart Apache through Plesk. When I click "Restart", i'm getting the following message.

> Error: Unable to make action: Unable to manage service by
>   apache_control_adapter: Service /etc/init.d/httpd failed to start
>   ('--start', 'web')

I also tried(thanks to paulsm4 from stackoverflow to do it through the terminal. I typed

> sudo /etc/init.d/httpd start

and the error i got is:

> Starting httpd: (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind
>   to address [::]:80 (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not
>   bind to address 0.0.0.0:80 no listening sockets available, shutting
>   down Unable to open logs [FAILED]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

httpd seems to be still running in a bad state...

try:

```
# kill -9 $(pidof httpd)
# /etc/init.d/httpd start
```

You should also verify that logs exists and have good permissions.

Comment: Got a blank line on "".
And on the second line I got "Starting httpd: [  OK  ]".

can you where can i verify that logs exist?

Comment: if the output of `service httpd status` is *running*, that's ok. I don't use RH or derivated, but debian, so i think (i can be wrong) that logs are in /var/log/httpd/{access,error}.log

Comment: When i edit/access the php.ini file and the log files as you said, I see that they are empty.

Comment: Also when i login to the server and type "ls", I get
"install.log
install.log.syslog
kmod-microsoft-hyper-v-rhel63.3.4-1.20120727.i686.rpm
kmod-microsoft-hyper-v-rhel63.3.4-1.20120727.x86_64.rpm
microsoft-hyper-v-debuginfo-rhel63.3.4-1.20120727.i686.rpm
....
microsoft-hyper-v-rhel63.3.4-1.20120727.src.rpm
microsoft-hyper-v-rhel63.3.4-1.20120727.x86_64.rpm
parallels
plesk10-install.log
plesk-installer.log
ZendGuardLoader-php-5.3-linux-glibc23-x86_64
ZendGuardLoader-php-5.3-linux-glibc23-x86_64.tar.gz"

So I guess something's wrong there.

Comment: ls command list your actual working directory. That means your user directory contains  a lot of redhat packages(rpm), that's not clean but this is not a problem. Logs can be anywhere, depending on your plesk config. Is the webapp ok now?

Comment: Apache is still down. I'm kinda lost! Don't know what to do.

Comment: what is the output of `pgrep -l -u apache` and `pidof httpd`

Comment: Both return nothing. Just going to the next line.

Comment: ok and `sudo fuser 80/tcp`

Comment: It returns
"80/tcp:               7168"

Comment: ok now `ps 7168`

Comment: PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND

(I guess it's empty)

Comment: wow... can you type `sudo fuser 80/tcp` again

Comment: Sure.
Still getting nothing. Just skips to the next line.

Comment: so try to start `service httpd start`

Comment: Still the same message:
"Starting httpd: (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
[FAILED]"